# How to pass external jar through the commnadline while running MapReduce?

Tags: hadoop-streaming

I use nltk within Python MapReduce program and use the below command to execute it.

I have found out that I am not able to pass nltk correctly along with the command. Could anyone let me know what is the correct syntax? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let me attempt to provide an answer. Please get back to me if it doesn't work for you.

May be you can try the following. Since, you are already using the `-file` option to pass the Mapper.py, using only ussing -mapper Mapper.py should do and try to use `-libjars` instead of `-archives`, if you need the classes inside nltk.jar in classpath.

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/gphd/hadoop-mapreduce-2.0.2_alpha_gphd_2_0_1_0/hadoop-streaming-2.0.2-alpha-gphd-2.0.1.0.jar \
-libjars senti-data/nltk.jar \
-file senti-data/traintweets.csv \
-file senti-data/stopwords.txt \
-file /home/cduser/senti-data/Mapper.py \
-mapper Mapper.py \
-input senti-data/inputtweets.txt \
-output output
```

Comment: But in your question you used senti-data/nltk.jar. Why is it then?
Anyways, Hadoop is a distributed computing framework, so my guess would be for `import nltk` to work, you need to install NLTK in all the machines(nodes), which are part of the cluster.